# Exam class: labels "point", "points" and "score" in spanish

Tags: exam, spanish

I'm using the exam class with `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` and when I type `\gradetable[v]` the labels appears in english. The question name can be changed using `\vqword{newlabelname}` but I don't know how to change the others.

On the other hand, `\question[3]` write "3 points" and `\question[1]` "1 point". I want to change to the spanish words "3 puntos" and "1 punto".

Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\vqword{Problema}
\addpoints
\gradetable[v]

\begin{questions}
\addpoints
\question[5] Una pregunta.

\addpoints
\question[12] Otra pregunta, un poco más difícil.

\addpoints
\question[3] Una pregunta más sencilla

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to make it easier to find a solution? However the manual mentions the possibility of adding `\pointpoints{punto}{puntos}` in the preamble which might solve the problem.

Comment: I think I've found a solution: typing `\vpword{label_points}`, `\vsword{label_score}` and `\vtword{label_total}` seems to solve the problem. This is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many customizable fixed words in the `exam` class. You can find all of them in the manual. For your example this suffices:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\pointpoints{punto}{puntos}
\hpword{Puntos:}
\vpword{Puntos}
\htword{Totale}
\vtword{Totale:}
\vsword{Resultado}

\begin{document}

\vqword{Problema}
\addpoints
\gradetable[v]

\begin{questions}
\addpoints
\question[1] Una pregunta.

\addpoints
\question[12] Otra pregunta, un poco más difícil.

\addpoints
\question[3] Una pregunta más sencilla

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]