# Redefining \pointname for exam class

Tags: exam, arabic

```
I want to use to customize commands in exam.cls to my use. The point 1 for general 
purpose and the point 2 for use in arabic language

1/ The first customization concerns the environment ''oneparchoices'', which puts 
several choices in the same line, by the commands: 
  \begin{oneparchoices}
  \choice choice1
  \choice choice2
  \choice choice3
  \end{oneparchoices}
  I want to have different choices separated by a fixed distance on the line, for   
  every length of the "body of the choice" (which is not too long, a number in almost
  every case...) 
  For example...  Choice A, after 3cm  choice B, after 2cm  choice C... etc

2/ The second problem is about the customization of the command '\thepoints', which 
is always replaced by ``\@points \@pointname'' if the number of points has been 
specified for the question.
For the same purpose of using the command ''\pointpoints{point}{points}'', where 
'\pointname' is replaced by ''point'' when \@points=1 or=1/2, and replaced  by 
''points'' when \@points > 1, I want to customize the command '\thepoints' because 
that, in arabic language, we have four cases instead of two: The cases '\@points=1', 
'\@points=2', '3<=\@points<=10', and '\@points>10'.
Then, '\@pointname' will have 4 different names, say {WORD_1,WORD_2,WORD_3,WORD_4}.

So I want to write a macro that replaces "\thepoints" by:
-   "WORD_1" if '\@points=1' (Note that \@points is not written here...)
-   "WORD_2" if '\@points=2' (Note that \@points is not written here too...)
-   "\@points WORD_3" if '3<= \@points <=10' (Here \@points must be written...)
-   "\@points WORD_4" if '\@points >10' (Here \@points must be written here too...)

More precisely, I want, for example, that the commands:
\question[1] gives:  **Question  (WORD_1)**
\question[2] gives:  **Question  (WORD_2)**
\question[8] gives:  **Question  (8 WORD_3)**
\question[14] gives:  **Question  (14 WORD_4)**
```

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136569/exam-class-labels-point-points-and-score-in-spanish ?

Comment: The question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136569/exam-class-labels-point-points-and-score-in-spanish is not in relation with my problem, because in latin languages, there is 2 cases, singular and plural. In arabic there is 4 cases, case 1, case 2, case smaller then 10, and case greater than 10