# Customizing \pointpoints in exam class for more forms than just singular and plural

Tags: languages, polyglossia, exam

I re-send a problem, posted with an other, here
[Redefining \pointname for exam class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226065/redefining-pointname-for-exam-class)

I have a problem, related with the customization of the command ''\thepoints'' in Exam class. The command, ''\thepoints'', in Exam.cls is always replaced by ``@points @pointname'' if the number of points has been specified for the question. (@points is the point entry and @pointname is the pointname.

This pointname is defined by the command ''\pointpoints{point}{points}'', where
'\pointname' is replaced by ''point'' when @points=1 or=1/2 (singular) and replaced  by
''points'' when @points > 1 (plural).

I want to customize the command '\thepoints' for other languages (specifically Arabic) where can be more than two cases, e.g. four: the cases '@points=1 or=1/2',
'@points=2', '3<=@points<=10', and '@points>10').

Then, '@pointname' will have 4 different values-names, say {WORD_1, WORD_2, WORD_3, WORD_4}.

So I want to write a macro that replaces "\thepoints" by:

- "WORD_1" if '@points=1 or=1/2'' (Note that @points is not written here...)
- "WORD_2" if '@points=2' (Note that @points is not written here too...)
- "@points WORD_3" if '3<= @points <=10' (Here we write the value of @points...)
- "@points WORD_4" if '@points >10' (Here @points must be written here too...)

More precisely, I want, for example, that the commands:

\question[1] gives:  **Question  (WORD_1)**

\question[2] gives:  **Question  (WORD_2)**

\question[8] gives:  **Question  (8 WORD_3)**

\question[14] gives:  **Question  (14 WORD_4)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of `\points` macro in the exam.cls is :

```
\newcommand\points{%
  \begingroup
    \let\half=\relax
    \edef\pt@string{\@points}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{1} \or \equal{\pt@string}{\half}}
          {\point@sing}{\point@plur}%
  \endgroup
}
```

you can make more cases (four) inside conditional `ifthenelse` like this

```
\renewcommand\points{%
  \begingroup
    \let\half=\relax
    \edef\pt@string{\@points}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{1} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{\half}}
    {\point@labelone}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{2}}{\point@labeltwo}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{3} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{3\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{4} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{4\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{5} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{5\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{6} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{6\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{7} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{7\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{8} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{8\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{9} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{9\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{10}\OR \equal{\pt@string}{10\half}}
     {\point@labelthree}{\point@labelfour}}}
          %
  \endgroup
}
```

here you obtain what you need. perhaps there is a shorter way to do that.

And you can test it with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}

\def\sample{What is the Pythagorean theorem}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\point@labelone{word-1}
\newcommand\point@labeltwo{word-2}
\newcommand\point@labelthree{word-3}
\newcommand\point@labelfour{word-4}


\renewcommand\points{%
  \begingroup
    \let\half=\relax
    \edef\pt@string{\@points}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{1} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{\half}}
    {\point@labelone}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{2}}{\point@labeltwo}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{3} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{3\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{4} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{4\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{5} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{5\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{6} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{6\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{7} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{7\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{8} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{8\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{9} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{9\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{10}\OR \equal{\pt@string}{10\half}}
     {\point@labelthree}{\point@labelfour}}}
          %
  \endgroup
}

\makeatother

\pointformat{(\thepoints)}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[\half] \sample

\question[1] \sample

\question[2] \sample

\question[4] \sample

\question[12] \sample

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

To remove `\@points` from the `\thepoints` macro in case word-1 and word-2 I can't find the original definition of `\thepoints` in exam.cls, with work around  you can change its definition with the help of `\pointformat`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}

\def\sample{What is the Pythagorean theorem}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\point@labelone{word-1}
\newcommand\point@labeltwo{word-2}
\newcommand\point@labelthree{word-3}
\newcommand\point@labelfour{word-4}


\renewcommand\points{%
  \begingroup
    \let\half=\relax
    \edef\pt@string{\@points}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{1} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{\half}}
    {\point@labelone}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{2}}{\point@labeltwo}{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{3} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{3\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{4} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{4\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{5} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{5\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{6} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{6\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{7} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{7\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{8} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{8\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{9} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{9\half}%
    \OR \equal{\pt@string}{10}\OR \equal{\pt@string}{10\half}}
     {\point@labelthree}{\point@labelfour}}}
          %
  \endgroup
}

\renewcommand\thepoints{%
  \if@placepoints
    \if@bonus
      \@points \@bonuspointname 
    \else
    \let\half=\relax
    \edef\pt@string{\@points}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pt@string}{1} \OR \equal{\pt@string}{\half}%
                                      \OR \equal{\pt@string}{2}}
    {\@pointname}{\@points \@pointname}
     \fi
  \fi
}% thepoints

\makeatother

\pointformat{(\thepoints)}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question[\half] \sample

\question[1] \sample

\question[2] \sample

\question[4] \sample

\question[12] \sample

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

We obtain:

[image]

Comment: I've tested your solution and it does what I wanted. Thanks