# latex exam template in greek language

Tags: templates

I use the following exam template

[exam](http://www.math.umn.edu/~rogness/math8001/handouts/math_exam_template.tex)

I want to prepare an exam but using the greek language.
For example

```
% Exam Template for UMTYMP and Math Department courses
%
% Using Philip Hirschhorn's exam.cls: http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/#ExamCls
%
% run pdflatex on a finished exam at least three times to do the grading table on front page.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% These lines can probably stay unchanged, although you can remove the last
% two packages if you're not making pictures with tikz.
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\RequirePackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsmath, latexsym, verbatim, xspace, setspace,enumerate}
\RequirePackage{tikz, pgflibraryplotmarks}

\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

% By default LaTeX uses large margins.  This doesn't work well on exams; problems
% end up in the "middle" of the page, reducing the amount of space for students
% to work on them.
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}


% Here's where you edit the Class, Exam, Date, etc.
\newcommand{\class}{Μηχανική Στερεού Σώματος}
\newcommand{\term}{Σχολική Περίοδος 2015-2016}
\newcommand{\examnum}{Εξέταση 1}
\newcommand{\examdate}{29/2/2016}
\newcommand{\timelimit}{120 Λεπτά}

% For an exam, single spacing is most appropriate
\singlespacing
% \onehalfspacing
% \doublespacing

% For an exam, we generally want to turn off paragraph indentation
\parindent 0ex

\begin{document} 

% These commands set up the running header on the top of the exam pages
\pagestyle{head}
\firstpageheader{}{}{}
\runningheader{\class}{\examnum\ - Σελίδα \thepage\ από \numpages}{\examdate}
\runningheadrule

\begin{flushright}
\begin{tabular}{p{2.8in} r l}
\textbf{\class} & \textbf{Ονοματεπώνυμο:} & \makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}\\
\textbf{\term} &&\\
\textbf{\examnum} &&\\
\textbf{\examdate} &&\\
\textbf{Χρόνος: \timelimit} & Υπεύθυνος Καθηγητής: & \makebox[2in]{\hrulefill}
\end{tabular}\\
\end{flushright}
\rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{.1pt}

Αυτή η εξέταση περιέχει \numpages\ σελίδες (συμπεριλαμβανόμενης της παρούσης) και \numquestions\ προβλήματα. Ελέξτε εάν κάποια σελίδα λείπει. Εισάγετε όλες τις απαιτούμενες πληροφορίες στην κορυφή αυτής της σελίδας και βάλτε τα αρχικά σας στην κορυφή κάθε σελίδας. \\
%This exam contains \numpages\ pages (including this cover page) and
%\numquestions\ problems.  Check to see if any pages are missing.  Enter
%all requested information on the top of this page, and put your initials
%on the top of every page, in case the pages become separated.\\

\textit{ΔΕΝ} επιτρέπεται να χρησιμοποιήσετε βιβλία, οποιοδήποτε είδος σημειώσεων και υπολογιστή τσέπης σε αυτήν την εξέταση.\\
%You may \textit{not} use your books, notes, or any calculator on this exam.\\

Απαιτείται να δείξετε την δουλειά σας σε κάθε πρόβλημα αυτής της εξέτασης. Οι ακόλουθοι κανόνες πρέπει να εφαρμοστούν:\\
%You are required to show your work on each problem on this exam.  The following rules apply:\\

\begin{minipage}[t]{3.7in}
\vspace{0pt}
\begin{itemize}

\item \textbf{Εάν χρησιμοποιήσετε κάποιον φυσικό νόμο πρέπει να δηλώσετε σαφώς την χρήση του} και να εξηγήσετε γιατί τον χρησιμοποιήσετε.
\item \textbf{Οργανώστε την δουλειά σας} με καθαρό, λογικό και με συνοχή τρόπο στον χώρο που σας έχει παραχωρηθεί. Τυχόν λύση διάσπαρτη σε όλη τη σελίδα χωρίς σαφή ακολουθία βημάτων θα δημιουργήσει αρνητική εντύπωση.
\item \textbf{Μυστηριώδεις ή ανυποστήρικτος απαντήσεις δεν θα λάβουν πλήρη βαθμολογία.} Μία σωστή απάντηση ανυποστήρικτη από υπολογισμούς, εξήγηση ή αλγεβρική δουλειά \underline{ΔΕΝ} θα λάβει μηδενική βαθμολογία. Μία λανθασμένη απάντηση η οποία υποστηρίζεται από ουσιαστικά σωστούς υπολογισμούς και εξηγήσεις μπορεί παρόλα αυτά να λάβει μέρος της βαθμολογίας.
\item Εάν χρειάζεστε περισσότερο χώρο, χρησιμοποιήστε το πίσω μέρος των σελίδων, δηλώνοντας σαφώς πότε το κάνετε αυτό.
%\item \textbf{If you use a ``fundamental theorem'' you must indicate this} and explain
%why the theorem may be applied.
%
%\item \textbf{Organize your work}, in a reasonably neat and coherent way, in
%the space provided. Work scattered all over the page without a clear ordering will 
%receive very little credit.  
%
%\item \textbf{Mysterious or unsupported answers will not receive full
%credit}.  A correct answer, unsupported by calculations, explanation,
%or algebraic work will receive no credit; an incorrect answer supported
%by substantially correct calculations and explanations might still receive
%partial credit.


%\item If you need more space, use the back of the pages; clearly indicate when you have done this.
\end{itemize}

Μην γράψετε στον πίνακα που βρίσκεται στα δεξιά.
%Do not write in the table to the right.
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{2.3in}
\vspace{0pt}
%\cellwidth{3em}
\gradetablestretch{2}
\vqword{Πρόβλημα}
\addpoints % required here by exam.cls, even though questions haven't started yet.  
\gradetable[v]%[pages]  % Use [pages] to have grading table by page instead of question

\end{minipage}
\newpage % End of cover page

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% See http://www-math.mit.edu/~psh/#ExamCls for full documentation, but the questions
% below give an idea of how to write questions [with parts] and have the points
% tracked automatically on the cover page.
%
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{questions}

% Basic question
\addpoints
\question[10] Θεωρούμε δύο σημεία ενός δίσκου, ο οποίος περιστρέφεται γύρω από σταθερό άξονα που διέρχεται από το κέντρο του και είναι κάθετος στο επίπεδο που ορίζει ο δίσκος με αυξανόμενη γωνιακή ταχύτητα. Το ένα σημείο βρίσκεται στην περιφέρεια το δίσκου και το άλλο στο μισό της απόστασης μεταξύ της περιφέρειας και του κέντρου. 
\begin{enumerate}[i.]
\item Ποιο σημείο καλύπτει την μεγαλύτερη απόσταση σε ένα δεδομένο χρονικό διάστημα$;$
\item Ποιο σημείο διαγράφει την μεγαλύτερη γωνία$;$
\item Ποιο σημείο έχει την μεγαλύτερη ταχύτητα$;$
\item Ποιο σημείο έχει την μεγαλύτερη επιτρόχια επιτάχυνση$;$
\item Ποιο σημείο έχει την μεγαλύτερη κεντομόλα επιτάχυνση$;$
\end{enumerate}

%Two points are on a disk that is turning about a fixed-axis through its
%center, perpendicular to the disk and through its center, at increasing angular
%velocity. One point on the rim and the other point is halfway between the rim and
%the center. (a) Which point moves the greater distance in a given time? (b) Which
%point turns through the greater angle? (c) Which point has the greater speed?
%(d) Which point has the greater angular speed? (e) Which point has the greater
%tangential acceleration? (f) Which point has the greater angular acceleration?
%(g) Which point has the greater centripetal acceleration

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the table with the credit (partial, total etc) appears with headings with english names. How can I modify the table's headings?

Thanks!

Comment: I apologize. I have completely forgotten this question. Thanks a lot for pointing it out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `exam` class maintains a list of keywords:

```
\hqword{Question:}
\hpgword{Page:}
\hpword{Points:}
\hsword{Score:}
\htword{Total}
\vpword{Points}
\vsword{Score}
\vtword{Total:}
\vqword{Question}
\vpgword{Page}

\bhqword{Question:}
\bhpgword{Page:}
\bhpword{Bonus Points:}
\bhsword{Score:}
\bhtword{Total}
\bvqword{Question}
\bvpgword{Page}
\bvpword{Bonus Points}
\bvsword{Score}
\bvtword{Total:}

\chqword{Question:}
\chpgword{Page:}
\chpword{Points:}
\chbpword{Bonus Points:}
\chsword{Score:}
\chtword{Total}
\cvqword{Question}
\cvpgword{Page}
\cvpword{Points}
\cvbpword{Bonus Points}
\cvsword{Score}
\cvtword{Total:}
```

You should add these lines in your document preamble, with appropriate translations.

For instance, if I add

```
\vtword{Σύνολο}
```

the table of scores becomes

[image]

In order to change the keyword issued when `\addpoints` is in force, add also

```
\pointpoints{point}{points} % <---- Translate into Greek
```

See [Exam class: labels "point", "points" and "score" in spanish](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136569/exam-class-labels-point-points-and-score-in-spanish)

Comment: Thanks! It works as desired. What should I do so that the command \addpoints
\question[10] ` return greek test (it returns 10 points)?